# use parseFloat while checking for NULL values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsefloat

In AngularJS, I am trying to figure out how many hours, for a current worker, are standard vs overtime. I have a formula that works well, if the hours are integers, but fails if it has decimals.

I have to account for situations where one of the numbers may not have been provided. This is my current approach:

```
laborItem.StraightHours = (parseFloat((laborItem.HoursB4Today | 0)) + parseFloat(laborItem.Hours | 0)) < 40 ?
                    (parseFloat(laborItem.Hours | 0)) :
                    40 - parseFloat(laborItem.HoursB4Today | 0);
```

This returns only the whole hours.

I have also tried:

```
laborItem.StraightHours = (parseFloat((laborItem.HoursB4Today | 0).toFixed(2)) + parseFloat(laborItem.Hours | 0).toFixed(2)) < 40 ?
                    (parseFloat(laborItem.Hours | 0).toFixed(2)) :
                    40 - parseFloat(laborItem.HoursB4Today | 0).toFixed(2);
```

But, this just adds two decimals. I need to preserve the decimal values.

How do I modify my formula to get this to work? And, do I really need to use `parseFloat` at all, or is there another/better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following code

```
laborItem.HoursB4Today = parseFloat(laborItem.HoursB4Today || 0);
laborItem.Hours = parseFloat(laborItem.Hours || 0);
laborItem.StraightHours = (laborItem.HoursB4Today + laborItem.Hours) < 40 ? laborItem.Hours : 40 - laborItem.HoursB4Today;
```

I just modified you code little bit but this can ensure that the future usage of the variables (HoursB4Today,Hours) of **laborItem** gurantees that they are pointing to a numeric values. You don't need to parse them again and again.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you rather want to use `||` instead of `|` in e.g. `laborItem.HoursB4Today | 0`

A single pipe is the bit-wise OR operator and 'converts' your numbers - if existing - into integers. The `||` is usually used to provide a default value in case the first operand evaluates to `false`.

So try changing the expressions like

```
laborItem.HoursB4Today | 0
```

into

```
laborItem.HoursB4Today || 0
```

Comment: I will have to try this and see.